# How can I put pins based on three codes from my sql?

Tags: swift

I'm new to swift, very difficult to figure it out. need your help. I just want to put pins on map but it doesnt work because of "var aboce" I think. need your help. I just want to know how i can add some pins based on the information above. Also please let me know if there is some mistakes on my codes.

```
import UIKit
import Mapkit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // MapViewを生成.
        var myMapView: MKMapView = MKMapView()
        myMapView.frame = self.view.frame

        // 経度、緯度.
        let latArr: [Double] = [36.000208,36.000214,36.000218,36.000224]
        let lonArr: [Double] = [139.655055,139.655060,139.655065,139.655070]
        let user_idArr:[Int] = [20,30,40,50]

        **var aboce = (latArr,lonArr,user_idArr)

        // here is my concern. dont know why getting error cuz of this...
        let center: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(aboce)**

        // MapViewに中心点を設定.
        myMapView.setCenterCoordinate(center, animated: true)

        // 縮尺.
        // 表示領域.
        let mySpan: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
        let myRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, mySpan)

        // MapViewにregionを追加.
        myMapView.region = myRegion

        // viewにMapViewを追加.
        self.view.addSubview(myMapView)

        // ピンを生成.
        var myPin: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        // 座標を設定.
        myPin.coordinate = center

        // タイトルを設定.
        myPin.title = "タイトル"

        // サブタイトルを設定.
        myPin.subtitle = "サブタイトル"

        // MapViewにピンを追加.
        myMapView.addAnnotation(myPin)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` takes two parameters, a latitude and a longitude.  I would the suspect the compiler is complaining about you trying to use a single parameter.

Why not do:

```
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latArr[0], lonArr[0])
```

where `[0]` is whatever entry from the array you're trying to use?

Also, while we're on the subject, please make `mapView` a class property.  The way you have it now, you create it in `viewDidLoad` and you add it to your view and then you immediately lose the reference to it when the `viewDidLoad` function finishes.

Comment: I just showed you what to do up there.  Is it confusing?